# How to get probability density function using Kullback-Leibler Divergence in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I have a set of 1D data saved in a python. I can get the probability density function using gaussian_kde function from scipy. I want to know whether the returned distribution matches with a theoretical distribution such as Normal distribution. For that can I use KL divergence? If so how can I use python to do that?

This is my python code to get the probability density function.

```
array = np.array(values)
KDEpdf = gaussian_kde(array)
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 1500)
kdepdf = KDEpdf.evaluate(x)
plt.plot(x, kdepdf, label="", color="blue")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Check scipy`s [entropy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html)-funciton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it:

1. Plot it against a normal fitted probability distribution. Like: `plt.hist(x, norm.pdf(x,mu, std))`
2. Compare kdepdf distribution with a uniform random dataset using something like `Q-Q plot` for both dataset.
3. Use *chi square test*, be cautious with the bin size you choose. Basically, this tests whether the number of draws that fall into various intervals is consistent with a uniform random distribution.chi square test. Basically, this tests whether the number of draws that fall into various intervals is consistent with a uniform random distribution.